# Need to match for a certain day using a timestamp in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Using example doc

```
{ "_id": {
    "$oid": "527339384bb8d32905f000853"
}, "format": "flat1", "aggregation": "raw", "vm_id": "10101010", "hostname": "foo.example.com", "fooid": "100822", "ts": {
    "$date": "2013-11-01T05:00:23.000Z"
}, "cpu_nanoseconds": 1410576880000000, "disk_usage": 20069460, "interface_public_rx_packets": 35771474, "interface_public_rx_bytes": 6023191691, "interface_public_rx_errors": 0, "interface_public_rx_drop": 0, "interface_public_tx_packets": 26004483, "interface_public_tx_bytes": 37293536055, "interface_public_tx_errors": 0, "interface_public_tx_drop": 0, "interface_private_rx_packets": 846833, "interface_private_rx_bytes": 63898435, "interface_private_rx_errors": 0, "interface_private_rx_drop": 0, "interface_private_tx_packets": 39, "interface_private_tx_bytes": 1638, "interface_private_tx_errors": 0, "interface_private_tx_drop": 0, "disk_primary_read_requests": 3280869, "disk_primary_read_bytes": 39818978304, "disk_primary_write_requests": 40331710, "disk_primary_write_bytes": 685420728320, "disk_swap_read_requests": 32, "disk_swap_read_bytes": 823808, "disk_swap_write_requests": 16, "disk_swap_write_bytes": 253952, "vcpu_nanoseconds_0": 470437920000000, "vcpu_nanoseconds_1": 344849460000000, "vcpu_nanoseconds_2": 342793890000000, "max_vcpus": 3}
```

I have the following query that groups information by day:

```
[ { "$match" : { "vm_id" : "1111223"}},
  { "$group" : {
                 "_id" : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$ts"},
                 "month" : { "$first" : { "$month" : "$ts"}},
                 "year" : { "$first" : { "$year" : "$ts"}},
                 "vm_id" : { "$first" : "$vm_id"},
                 "max_public_tx" : { "$max" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"},
                 "public_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"},
                 "public_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_rx_bytes"},
                 "private_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_tx_bytes"},
                 "private_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_rx_bytes"},
                 "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}
               },
  { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}}
]
```

So now I want to reduce it to hours for a particular day.
I thought all I needed was to change the _id and add another item to $match such as {{"$dayOfMonth" : "$ts"} :1} for the first day of the month but MongoDb hated that some much it hung my IDE.
What would be the proper $match query?

The query I'm working on currently:

```
[ { "$match" : { "vm_id" : "1111223",{ "$dayOfMonth" : "$ts"}: 1 }},
  { "$group" : {
                 "_id" : { "$hour" : "$ts"},
                 "day" : {"$first" : {"$dayOfMonth" : "$ts"}},
                 "month" : { "$first" : { "$month" : "$ts"}},
                 "year" : { "$first" : { "$year" : "$ts"}},
                 "vm_id" : { "$first" : "$vm_id"},
                 "max_public_tx" : { "$max" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"},
                 "public_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"},
                 "public_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_rx_bytes"},
                 "private_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_tx_bytes"},
                 "private_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_rx_bytes"},
                 "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}
               },
  { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}}
]
```

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to include the query that's actually causing the problem and a sample doc from the collection.

Comment: Can you add a sample doc from your collection to your post?

Comment: Why do you want to group by hour across multiple days?  that seems a bit strange - in fact your day aggregation groups by day of month across different months (and then ignores the month).  These are not actually correct (except for some small subset of data you may be testing with which will seem to show the correct results).

Answer (score 3):

Use $gte and $lt operator in your match pipeline, it will use your index (if ts is in an index), so your match pipeline will be :

```
{ "$match" : { "vm_id" : "1111223","ts" : {$gte:ISODate('2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'), $lt:ISODate('2013-11-02T00:00:00.000Z') }}},
```

Complete query :

```
[{ "$match" : { "vm_id" : "1111223","ts" : {$gte:ISODate('2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'), $lt:ISODate('2013-11-02T00:00:00.000Z') }}},  
{ "$group" : {
             "_id" : { "$hour" : "$ts"},
             "day" : {"$first" : {"$dayOfMonth" : "$ts"}},
             "month" : { "$first" : { "$month" : "$ts"}},
             "year" : { "$first" : { "$year" : "$ts"}},
             "vm_id" : { "$first" : "$vm_id"},
             "max_public_tx" : { "$max" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"},
             "public_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_tx_bytes"},
             "public_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_public_rx_bytes"},
             "private_tx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_tx_bytes"},
             "private_rx_total" : { "$sum" : "$interface_private_rx_bytes"},
             "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}
           },
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}}
]
```

Comment: Surely matching from the 1st to the 11th gives you 10 days of results not 1 days?

Comment: true I change the match in the complete query